# Recursion error for a algorithmic problem

Tags: python, arrays, loops, data-structures

I was trying to do the question- First negative integer in every windows of size k from a array (b) of size n.
I tried using recursion but the below error came. I am trying to figure out but didn't get my mistake. Please look into the code below

```
ans = []
def fnc(b,n,k):
    global ans
    dq = []
    
    for i in range(0,k):
        if b[i]<0:
            dq.append(b[i])
    if len(dq) != 0:
        ans.append(dq[0])
    else:
        ans.append(0)
        
    dq = []
    b.remove(b[0])
    bnew = b
    nnew = len(bnew)  # or nnew = n-1
    
    while len(bnew) > 1:
        fnc(bnew,nnew,k)
```

```
input:
B = [12, -1, -7, 8, -15, 30, 16, 28]
N = 8
K = 3
fnc( B, N, K)
print(ans)
```

Showing error List Index out of range

Comment: `bnew = b` doesn't do anything useful - it just creates another reference to the same list. You also don't need a `while` loop for the recursion part (though it happens to work in this case) - use `if` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are recursively removing the first element of B, so in the run you will encounter the state where len(b) < k, so I would recommend to change the while loop to :

```
while len(bnew) > k:
   fnc(bnew,nnew,k)
```

Comment: thanks that corrected the code. But when I add new values. The output is also returning answer of the previous values entered.

Comment: @BishalHazarika could you explain in more detail what you mean with that? What is your input and what output do you expect?

Comment: I think it should be `len(bnew) >= k` to include the final window